# What is 'PrimaryKey' converted to by SQL Server Migration Assistant for Access/SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access-2016, sql-server-migration-assi

I've put an Access database into SQL Server Migration Assistant for Access and created a report (I haven't sent anything to the server). I'm getting the following info msg: "A2SS0029: Primary key name 'PrimaryKey' was changed during conversion."

I'm assuming PrimaryKey is internal to Access. Can anyone confirm that? It's definitely not the primary key field-name.

Does anyone know what it would be changed to? I guess it's the internal name of PKs in SQL Server.

Comment: Can you state the data types in MS Access which are failing to migrate to SQL Server? also give the highest value of the example column that's failing to migrate and the lowest value.

Comment: "I haven't sent anything to the server." And it's not an error, it's an informational message.

Comment: It's really just terminology I guess. I'm just trying to keep track of what's going on under the hood. "...name 'PrimaryKey' was changed during conversion." Ok, where did that come from and what's it being changed to? Could use more info from SSMA.